# Jenkins Build Trigger "Enable Artifactory trigger" is not working with JFrog

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, jfrog-cli

We are using JFrog as artifactory and Jenkins is our CI/CD tool. I have created a Jenkins which should run upon an artifact gets published to jfrog artifactory. But seems to be the plugin is not working as expected. When i googled, found the below URL and as per URL its applicable only for JFrog Pro-version. https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-1138

My question is, this option applicable only for JFrog pro-version or am i missing something here.

Thanks,
Srikanth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Artifactory Trigger feature in Jenkins, allowing to trigger Jenkins jobs following changes in pre-configired paths in Artifactory, requires at least an Artifactory Pro license.

Comment: It means JFrog Pro License?

Comment: JFrog Artifactory Pro license.